# Powershell commandline with pipes error using Exchange 2010

Tags: powershell, exchange-server

Being new to powershell and used to oneliners in unix I find powershell strange. The below code gives me a "too many pipes" type of error. Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong. My last step will be to add code that adds permission if not found in the else block.

```
[PS] C:\Windows\system32>(Get-mailbox -identity moh | select alias, distinguishedname) | foreach-object -process { if($_.distinguishedname -match "HK1|VO[1-9]") { $alias = $_.alias; get-mailboxfolderstatistics -identity $alias | Where {$_.FolderType -eq 'Calendar'} | %{ $calpath = $_.folderpath.substring(1); Get-MailboxFolderPermission -Identity $alias":\"$calpath -User iTell | %{ if($_.AccessRights -eq 'Editor') { write-host "Editor!" } else { write-host $_.AccessRights }} } } }
```

I get the following error.

```
Pipeline not executed because a pipeline is already executing. Pipelines cannot be executed concurrently.
+ CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped:   (Microsoft.Power...tHelperRunspace:ExecutionCmdletHelperRunspace) [], PSInvalidOperationException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : RemotePipelineExecutionFailed
```

Answer (score 0):

Got it. Had to encapsulate blocks of code with parenthesis. But I thought the pipe block was just some sort of a write lock. In here I was only getting data and hence ought to be able to read from the streams.